# Divs not aligned vertical on smartphone and small browsers

Tags: html, css, magento

My divs does not stack with vertical alignment:

Fine when horisontal:
[image]

Not aligned when vertical:

[image]

I write internal css because i us text editors in Magento to insert my pages.

https://jsfiddle.net/mastervision/8qqtadv0/

```
<div style="width:500 px">
<div style="float:left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 0px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #021a40; width:100 px"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/6ypsoh.png" alt="" /></div>
<div style="float:left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 7px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #021a40; width:100 px"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/6ypsoh.png" alt="" /></div>
<div style="float:left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 7px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #021a40; width:100 px"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/6ypsoh.png" alt="" /></div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your just forget a padding on your 1st div. This should work.

```
<div style="width:500 px">
<div style="float:left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 7px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #021a40; width:100 px"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/6ypsoh.png" alt="" /></div>
<div style="float:left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 7px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #021a40; width:100 px"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/6ypsoh.png" alt="" /></div>
<div style="float:left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 7px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #021a40; width:100 px"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/6ypsoh.png" alt="" /></div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd and 3rd div has extra left `margin` of `7px` set keep it same for all like

```
margin: 0px 7px 0px 0px;
```

**Example:**

```
<div style="float:left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 0px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #021a40; width:100 px"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRHxA.png" alt="" /></div>
<div style="float:left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 0px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #021a40; width:100 px"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRHxA.png" alt="" /></div>
<div style="float:left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 0px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #021a40; width:100 px"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRHxA.png" alt="" /></div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

if you want it aligned vertically and horizontally then add `7px` to first `div` too

```
margin: 0px 7px 0px 7px;
```

**Example:**

```
<div style="float:left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 7px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #021a40; width:100 px"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRHxA.png" alt="" /></div>
<div style="float:left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 7px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #021a40; width:100 px"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRHxA.png" alt="" /></div>
<div style="float:left; margin: 0px 7px 0px px; line-height: 0; border: 1px solid #021a40; width:100 px"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRHxA.png" alt="" /></div>
```

[image]

[image]
    [image]

Answer (score 1):

You have slightly different margins for the first div - it's showing as having 0 pixels left margin, whereas the other 2 both have a 7 pixel left margin.

Answer (score 1):

It was working fine, you entered 0px instead of 7px.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Added left and right `margin` to the three divs equally, and added negative `margin` to outer div. So it will have same spacing in larger screen, and also align in small screen.

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/8qqtadv0/1/